# How can I send the primary key to a user using Azure APIM?

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I am using Azure APIM to control how users interact with my API. Suppose I disable the need for approval for a user to fully access my API. How can I send a new user their authorization key (i.e., primary key) to their email?

I am aware they can log in the Developer Portal and get this information from their profile. But I am looking for a way to do this programatically.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send a new user their authorization key, you can use Azure management API to do this, just try the code below to get all authorization keys of a user by user email:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import requests

resource_group = ''
APIM_name = ''
sub_id = ''
client_id = ''
client_secret =  ''
tenant_id = ''

user_email = ''

mgmt_Base_URL = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/"+sub_id+"/resourceGroups/"+resource_group+"/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/"+APIM_name

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id = client_id,
    client_secret = client_secret,
    tenant_id = tenant_id 
)

accessToken = credentials.get_token('https://management.azure.com/.default')

def __main__():
    user = findUserByEmail(user_email)
    if user:
        subs = listSubOfUser(user['name'])['value']
        print("user subscriptions:")
        for sub in subs:
           
            print("name:"+ sub['properties']['displayName'] + " keys:")
            subKeys = getKeysBySubID(sub['id'])
            print(subKeys['primaryKey'])
            print(subKeys['secondaryKey'])
    else:
        print("no such user")


def findUserByEmail(email):
    reqURL =mgmt_Base_URL+ "/users?api-version=2019-12-01&$filter=email eq '" + email + "'"
    r= requests.get(reqURL,headers={"Authorization":"Bearer " + accessToken.token})
    result = r.json()
    if(len(result['value'])>0):
        return result['value'][0]   
    else:
        return None


def listSubOfUser(userID):
    reqURL = mgmt_Base_URL + "/subscriptions?api-version=2019-12-01&$filter=ownerId eq '"+userID+"'"
    r= requests.get(reqURL,headers={"Authorization":"Bearer " + accessToken.token})
    return r.json()

def getKeysBySubID(SubID):
    reqURL = "https://management.azure.com"  +SubID+"/listSecrets?api-version=2019-12-01"
    r= requests.post(reqURL,headers={"Authorization":"Bearer " + accessToken.token})
    return r.json()

__main__()
```

I have tested on my side and it works for me:
[image]

[image]

More operations about [APIM management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/).

Comment: Thank you very much, Stanley. You solved my problem. Cheers!